# Design Issues with Windows Phone 8 Development

Tags: windows-phone-8

As the WP8  has many Emulaotors and works on different resolutions, I was following the following link , but the code doesnt seem to work .
Kindly Check Point 4 , Point 6 and point 7

**[Multi-resolution apps for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974(v=vs.105).aspx)**

The code is giving errors . Kindly check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error in the code. Change this line in step 4:

```
public class MultiResImageChooserUri
```

to this:

```
public class MultiResImageChooser
```

Then it should work.

**Edit:** The article doesn't mention namespaces at all and so I'm assuming that is your issue here. In step 6 it says to add the xaml namespace:

```
xmlns:h="clr-namespace:MultiResSnippet"
```

So based on that you need to make sure your class is in the MultiResSnippet namespace (or change this to your own namespace).

So make sure your code is:

using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

```
namespace MultiResSnippet
{
  public class MultiResImageChooser
  {
     ...
  }
}
```

Learn more [about xaml namespaces here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms747086%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Kindly look at the XAML namespace ! Its not working . Point 6 and 7

Comment: so if my app name is different so the namespace should be replaced by the one I have sir?

Comment: You need to use whatever namespace you have in your code. So if you use the code in my edit with the namespace then you use that namespace. If you've used a different namespace then you will have to change your xaml namespace to the one you used.

Comment: I am getting the following errors    Error  MultiResImageChooser is not supported in a Silverlight project.

Comment: actually there are 10 errors -"the namespace prefix h is not defined"

Comment: Is your project a Silverlight project or a Windows Phone 8 project?

Comment: Windows Phone 8 Project sir

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21567/discussion-between-bryant-and-user1606266)

Answer (score 0):

Just add your Project Name such as "PhoneApp" in APP.XAML

change your code: xmlns:h="clr-namespace:MultiResSnippet" to below one: xmlns:h="clr-namespace:PhoneApp.MultiResSnippet",  it works without errors.