# The tag 'MultiResImageChooser' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:MultiResSnippet'

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

I'm following this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974(v=vs.105).aspx

This is a fresh Windows Phone 8 project, with both the `ResolutionHelper` class and `MultiResImageChooser` class.

In `App.xaml`, I have added the namespace mapping, but when I add the application resource, I get an error from the compiler:

*`"The tag 'MultiResImageChooser' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:MultiResSnippet'"`*

Here is the code for App.xaml:

```
<Application
x:Class="Upgrade.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:h="clr-namespace:MultiResSnippet">


<!--Application Resources-->
<Application.Resources>
    <h:MultiResImageChooser x:Key="MultiResImageChooser"/>
</Application.Resources>

<Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
    <!--Required object that handles lifetime events for the application-->
    <shell:PhoneApplicationService
        Launching="Application_Launching" Closing="Application_Closing"
        Activated="Application_Activated" Deactivated="Application_Deactivated"/>
</Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the **Step 4**

Change this line:

```
public class MultiResImageChooserUri
```

to this one:

```
public class MultiResImageChooser
```

Comment: I tried that and nothing changes, I've tried doing this 3 different times with fresh projects and I still get the same error.

Comment: @BaileyStein Have look at this, here is the similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003748/design-issues-with-windows-phone-8-development

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the advice in Step 6

6.In App.xaml, in the  element, add the following xmlns namespace mapping.

XAML
xmlns:h="clr-namespace:MultiResSnippet"

The correct answer given by APAC/GCR Professional Support Team after I raise the same problem is given as follow:-

change your code: xmlns:h="clr-namespace:MultiResSnippet" 
to below one: xmlns:h="clr-namespace:PhoneApp.MultiResSnippet",  it works without errors.

which mean just add your Project "PhoneApp" name to solve the mistake. I had also provide feedback to
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Multi-resolution apps for Windows Phone 8
 39 out of 58 rated this helpful - Rate this topic
November 04, 2013
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
on Windows Phone | Dev Center